# Why does the execution time of my perl code vary so widely?

Tags: performance, perl

I found the following perl code executed in surprisingly varying speeds, sometimes fast, sometimes very slow. I have a few folders containing tens of thousands of files, which I need to run this code through. I am running this on cygwin with windows 7. Just wonder if someone could please help me to speed it up, or as least to figure out why the speed is varying. My CPU and memory should be plentiful in all these situations.

outer loop to iterate through a list of $dir's

```
opendir(DIR, $dir);
@all=readdir(DIR);
@files = (0..$#all);
$i=-1;
foreach $current (@all){     
    if (-f "$dir/$current") {
        $files[++$i]=$current;
    }
}
push @Allfiles,@files[0..$i];
closedir(DIR);
```

Comment: Are you doing anything else on your computer at the same time, like running bittorrent or a game server or similar?

Answer (score 7):

You're probably I/O bound, so changes to your code probably won't affect the total runtime - runtime will be affected by whether the directory entries are in cache or not.

But your code uses temporary arrays for no good reason, using too much RAM if the directories are very large. You could simplify it to:

```
opendir(DIR, $dir);
while (my file = readdir(DIR)) {
    push @Allfiles, $file if (-f "$dir/$file");
}
closedir(DIR);
```

No temporary arrays.

Comment: If the OP is severely memory bound, those temporary arrays may be swapping down to disk, slowing things down considerably (and ironically).

Comment: Hadn't thought about that - would have to be really big directories or really tight memory. Removing the temporaries would help a bit in that case, but `@Allfiles` itself might just get too big too in those circumstances... No real solution except breaking down the work in that case I guess.

Comment: You need to actually assign to $_ in the while() condition, as readdir() is not the special case that puts stuff into $_ for you.

Comment: @tadmc: I had tested that before posting it, and it had worked (perl 5.12 I think). But indeed it doesn't with the perl 5.8 I have here... or maybe I hadn't had enough coffee at the time and imagined the whole thing :-/ Fixed, thanks.

Comment: I tried exactly this code initially. It was quite slow. I then thought may be the list's pushes slowed things down. Therefore, I tried to allocate a long enough array first. So in your opinion, list's push or shift, for that matter, should not be the culprit for slow speed?

Comment: @QiangLi: compared to the I/O involved, I really doubt that the list extensions could be a problem.

Comment: @QiangLi => with disk io as part of the mix, you are not going to see any speed difference building the array incrementally with push vs preallocating it.

Comment: Just wonder, could the non-nativity of cygwin a cause of slow io? I used VB code before and it was fast to read those directories.

Comment: @QiangLi: could add a bit, but I'm not too familiar with cygwin. Please make sure your tests are really testing what you think they do - if your run your script in cygwin first, then a few minutes later in VB (and you don't have RAM shortage as you indicated), you're not testing anything. The OS will cache the directory entries, making subsequent lookups much faster (read from memory instead of disk).

Answer (score 4):

If it is slow the first time you run, and fast after that, then the problem is that your system is caching the reads. The first time you run your code, data has to be read off your disk. After that, the data is still cached in RAM. If you wait long enough, the cache will flush and you will have to hit the disks again.

Or sometimes you may be running some other disk intensive task at the same time, but not at other times when you run your code.

Comment: It is slow the first time, and some other non-first times too. I have 8GB memory, isn't this enough to keep the files in cache? BTW, I was not running other disk intensive tasks at the same time when I observed this.

Comment: Are you running anything memory intensive - like Firefox with a ton of tabs full of videos? 8GB should be more than plenty, unless the directory your are listing is full of tiny (under 4k) files.

Comment: no, no at all with those memory intensive tasks. that is why i was very curious to know why the difference among runs.